# Authorize .net not working in live server

Tags: php, codeigniter, authorize.net

I am using this code to create customer profile [Click here](http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#customer-profiles-create-customer-profile)

This is working fine in local but not working on live server. Showing 500 server error when execute the line no 58. (see sample code in above link)

My php version 5.4+ in server and met all requirement mentioned [here](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-php)

even all dependent library available in server which is required for this SDK

** working on sandbox

Comment: How many parameters are you passing in the set_data()? Also if possible then give code snippets so its easy to get clear idea about your issue.

Comment: code snippet given there. plz see the first link line 58

Comment: I already check both links your first link is display reference detail of Authorize  and I am asking for some code snippets. As per my knowledge you are missing some parameters that's main reason.

Comment: the link contain a "Sample Code" tab. plz see that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The classmap.php (in SDK) uses Camelcase for Symfony (directory) library which was wrong. After changing to lowercase of Symfony directory its working on live server.

https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-php/blob/master/classmap.php

line no 185 - 187